# Show div on mouse over of dynamic td

Tags: jquery, css

I want to show dynamic div for each dynamic td.

consider

```
<tr><td><a id=1>abc</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a id=1>cde</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a id=1>fgh</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a id=1>hij</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a id=1>klm</a></td></tr>
```

these tds wil be generated based on data from db.
i want to show a div on mouse over of  tag.
The main thing , how can i position the div for each  near that td

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [jQuery .hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

And the [jQueryUI position utility](http://jqueryui.com/demos/position/) to put the divs where you want them.

Below is an example.  You can do this many different ways.  I think the important thing is it appears the position() method doesn't work until the element is visible. At least that's what I experienced.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    * {font-family:Calibri}
    .data {width:100px;border:1px solid #000;display:none}
    .cell {width:200px;border:1px solid #ddd}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".cell").hover(
            function () {
                var $td = $(this);
                var divId = '#div-' + this.id.split('-')[1];
                //show it first or it doesn't position right
                $(divId).show();                
                $(divId).position({
                    my: 'left center',
                    at: 'right center',
                    of: $td,
                    collision: 'none'
                });
            },
            function () {
                var divId = '#div-' + this.id.split('-')[1];
                $(divId).hide();
            }
        );
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table width="200" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="2">
        <tr><td id="td-1" class="cell">Data</td></tr>
        <tr><td id="td-2" class="cell">Data</td></tr>
        <tr><td id="td-3" class="cell">Data</td></tr>
        <tr><td id="td-4" class="cell">Data</td></tr>
        <tr><td id="td-5" class="cell">Data</td></tr>
        <tr><td id="td-6" class="cell">Data</td></tr>
    </table>
    <div id="div-1" class="data">div-1</div>
    <div id="div-2" class="data">div-2</div>
    <div id="div-3" class="data">div-3</div>
    <div id="div-4" class="data">div-4</div>
    <div id="div-5" class="data">div-5</div>
    <div id="div-6" class="data">div-6</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This code, although conceptually correct, is horribly inefficient and could definitely do with some clean up.

Comment: @Yi, i wouldn't call it horrible for purposes of an example.  Not to mention I don't have the details of what the poster's markup and data really look like.  The idea was to show an example of the position feature not code it for them.

Comment: But in my screen there are different tds in one row. soi want to show the div over the td. thats is the main issue. in th given exampleshow hide of the div is working. But that is not exactly am looking for. div should display over particular td on mouseover

Comment: You can do that.  Take a look at the docs for the position utility. You just need to set the "my" and "at" correctly

Comment: http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/examples/positioning2.html  I was looking for something like this . this is css. now i have to do the jquery for dyanamic divs

Answer (score 2):

If you make the TDs `position:relative` You can add a hidden div with `position:absolute` to each TD that will appear on hover.

```
td { position:relative; }
.hidden_div { position:absolute; left:-9999em; }
td:hover .hidden_div { left:auto; top: 100%; }  /*adjust top*/
```

This will need a hack for ie6 though if you want to support that.

Answer (score 2):

**CSS:**

```
table td div { display:none; }
table tr:hover td div { display:block; }
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr><td><a id=1>abc</a><div>div1</div></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a id=1>cde</a><div>div2</div></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a id=1>fgh</a><div>div3</div></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a id=1>hij</a><div>div4</div></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a id=1>klm</a><div>div5</div></td></tr>
</table>
```

You can change `display:block` to `display:inline`

Comment: Concise & Clean. Thanks Jeaf :)